# Make a string refer to a form in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Ok i want the program to make some tables and for each table makes the table columns by a for loop 
this is my code :

```
   For i As Integer = 1 To Val(DatabaseCreationPage.TablesNumber.Text)
        cc.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE " & DatabaseTableCreationPage.tablesnames(i).Text
        cc.ExecuteNonQuery()
        If Val(DatabaseTableCreationPage.NumberOfColumnsInTable(i).Text) = 1 Then
            cc.CommandText = "ALTER TABLE " & DatabaseTableCreationPage.TablesNames(i).Text & " ADD " & set1.ColumnsNames(1).Text & " " & set1.TypeOfColumns(1).Text
            cc.ExecuteNonQuery()
        ElseIf Val(DatabaseTableCreationPage.NumberOfColumnsInTable(i).Text) = 2 Then
            For i1 As Integer = 1 To Val(DatabaseTableCreationPage.TablesNames(i).Text)
                cc.CommandText = "ALTER TABLE " & DatabaseTableCreationPage.TablesNames(i).Text & " ADD " & set1.ColumnsNames(i1).Text & " " & set1.TypeOfColumns(i1).Text
                cc.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Next
```

i want it to be :

```
   For i As Integer = 1 To Val(DatabaseCreationPage.TablesNumber.Text)
      dim setForms as string = "set" & i
        cc.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE " & DatabaseTableCreationPage.tablesnames(i).Text
        cc.ExecuteNonQuery()
        If Val(DatabaseTableCreationPage.NumberOfColumnsInTable(i).Text) = 1 Then
            cc.CommandText = "ALTER TABLE " & DatabaseTableCreationPage.TablesNames(i).Text & " ADD " & setForms.ColumnsNames(1).Text & " " & setForms.TypeOfColumns(1).Text
            cc.ExecuteNonQuery()
        ElseIf Val(DatabaseTableCreationPage.NumberOfColumnsInTable(i).Text) = 2 Then
            For i1 As Integer = 1 To Val(DatabaseTableCreationPage.TablesNames(i).Text)
                cc.CommandText = "ALTER TABLE " & DatabaseTableCreationPage.TablesNames(i).Text & " ADD " & setForms.ColumnsNames(i1).Text & " " & setSetForms.TypeOfColumns(i1).Text
                cc.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Next
```

because i have 10 set forms for table1 , table2 , table3 & etc

so i have set1 , set2, set3, set4 & etc

TablesNames and NumberOfColumnsInTable are arrays in one form it makes computer automatically creates TablesNames and NumberOfColumnsInTable according to the number of tables i have chosen  by :

```
dim TablesNames() As TextBox
ReDim TablesNames(DatabaseCreationPage.TablesNumber.Text)

    For TableNumber As Integer = 1 To val(DatabaseCreationPage.TablesNumber.Text)
       TablesNames(TableNumber) = New TextBox   
        With TablesNames(TableNumber)
            .Name = "textbox" & TableNumber.ToString
            .Size = New System.Drawing.Size(229, 20)
            .Location = New System.Drawing.Point(140, TableNumber * 25)
            .Enabled = True
            .Visible = True
        End With
        Me.Controls.Add(TablesNames(TableNumber))
    Next
```

NOTE : i can't Choose More Than 10 tables in each table i cant choose more than 10 columns

Comment: Don't start programming with code like that. Don't be lazy, provide meaningful names.

Comment: for counter as integer can be used thousands of times in one application. If it crashes for whatever reason, you will not have a very good time diagnosing the crash without meaningful names.

Comment: i meant i just wanted to make the string a part of the code so i can use it like a code not a string

Comment: This question gets asked just about every day. All it takes is a couple minutes of thinking. You want some forms, identified uniquely by some sort of index, and then you want to apply the same action to all of them. If only there was some sort of "list" you could put them in...

Comment: i know i can solve it by writing the code 10 times but i want a faster way because my real code is very big not such as this

Comment: forms are forms are objects.  strings are strings and NOT object references.  you cant do that and you really dont want to

Comment: As @TimSchmelter has mentioned, provide meaningful names. This is Fundamentals of Programming; it's much better to refer to a control with a meaningful name besides "form12" and so on as this can get really sloppy...

Comment: What do you mean with meaningful names ?

Comment: @MrCoDeXeR what do you mean with meaningful names

Comment: Generally speaking, 'meaningful names' are names that give some understanding of the function or purpose of the named object.

In the example given above, you would give names to each of your forms that give an idea of what they are for (so for example, a `main` form, an `upload` form, a `register` form, and so on)

Comment: Ok, this is clearly off topic from the original question you asked. Please start a new question stating where your having issues, don't change one that already had an answer to the original question...

Answer (score 2):

**Why use meaningful control names?**

The most common one that I see quite often is Hungarian naming convention and the Pascal naming Convention. Everyone has their own idea's as to these naming conventions, but here's a little breakdown in my opinion.

- lblFirstName- clearly we know this is a `Label` that should contain first name
- btnSave - clearly we should know this is a `Button` that calls a routine/method that would save data
- frmPerson - this should point out that this is a `Form` that would contain person details of some sort.

This is just a short example, you can find more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260976%28v=vs.60%29.aspx).
Another great read is provided by Joel Spolsky [here](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html)...

**As for your issue...**

```
 for counter as integer = 1 to 10
 dim forms as string = "form" & counter
 forms.textbox1.text = "test"
 next
```

In your example, you have a counter that just loops through and adds to a string, but then your using the `string.control.text` this doesn't work...

***Try this; and yes there are other ways as well...***

```
 Dim arrNames As New List(Of String) 'This will have all your strings in an array...
 For i As Integer = 1 To 10
  arrNames.Add(CStr("frm" & i.ToString()))
 Next
```

Now you have all your strings in a collection that you can use... Again, this is a bad idea; slap me for even doing something like this... You really should just name your controls first and then set some strings based on the control names themselves...